# Count cells with two conditions

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

We have a yearly calendar. https://ibb.co/8NcPM1y

In C10:C381 there are the weekdays (Monday-Sunday).
In columns E-W we have our employees.

The employees put an "18" in their cell if they work the late shift.
There is only one "18" per row (meaning only 1 employee works late every day)

My task is to count how often each employee works the late shift in a year.

I want to check Column C for "Friday".
If yes, check the corresponding row if there is an "18" in a cell.
If yes, count up for that employee/column.

I tried something similar to this:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Friday", C10:C381)), IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("18", INDEX(C10:C381, MATCH("Friday", C10:C381, 0)))), INDEX(C10:C381, MATCH("Freitag", C10:C381, 0)-8), ""), "")
```

Comment: Are the week days in C:C column as strings? Can that "18" marker be placed in other day except Friday? Is the marker really a string, or a number (in General format)?

Comment: Can you try `=COUNTIFS($C10:$C381,"Freitag", E10:E381,18)` and then pull the column through for each employee (as in to the right so the columns get adjusted)?

Comment: @FaneDuru 
1. yes they are string, everything is entered through strings.
2. yes, 18 is everyday once, so not fridays-exclusive
3. dont know, but people just put 18 from keyboard, so i guess string. The cell is in "Standard"

@ Notus_Panda excel says its an error with the formula (=1+1 equals 2) etc.

Comment: On **which row** are the employees names (E:W)? On the nineth one? And are the week days name in English or German?

Comment: @ FaneDuru
thats how it looks https://ibb.co/8NcPM1y
Employee names are on row 9

Comment: OK. I intended to post a VBA solution, to return a summary an another sheet (per employee/late shift count), but I can see you already received solutions using formulas.

Comment: Since you had commas here instead of semi-colon, I used commas hence your error @GPTBeratung ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls. try this
[image]

Copy function under all the WorkerX names.

Modify D3:D20 and C3:C20 according to the required size. Change Friday to the dayname which is required, or add additional daynames in the same mood. (C3:C20; "dayname")

Comment: this works well too, thank you!

Making my job easier, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUM(--(FILTER(E10:E381;C10:C381="Friday")=18))
```

Here is for employee in column E, filter his/her column where it is Friday, check for condition equal 18 and then sum the total cells where the condition is met. The double negative is a workaround to change the boolean result into 0/1 so it can sum. Hope I understand what you are looking for.

Comment: getting this error: https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vermeiden-defekter-formeln-8309381d-33e8-42f6-b889-84ef6df1d586?ns=excel&version=90&syslcid=1031&uilcid=1031&appver=zxl900&helpid=xlmain11.chm196624&ui=de-de&rs=de-de&ad=de

Comment: had to change the "," to ";" =SUM(--(FILTER(E10:E381   ;    C10:C381="Friday")=18))

and it works perfectly! thank you!

Comment: it worked for me, did you perhaps change the ","? Try this again =SUMME(--(FILTER(E10:E381;C10:C381="Friday")=18))